# Possible to "swap" OAuth2 Gmail API scopes?

Tags: gmail-api, google-email-settings-api

We have an app in the Google Apps Marketplace that currently uses the Email Settings API:

`https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/`

We use this to get a user's email signature.

This is being discontinued later this year, so we now want to move to the Gmail API and use this scope:

`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic`

We already have the Gmail "compose" scope, however this doesn't allow us to retrieve the signature.

We have over 250 businesses using our software and changing the scopes within the Marketplace SDK will trigger an *enormous* amount of stress / effort / confusion if end-customers have to re-authorise our App. We'd prefer not to inconvenience the end-customer when we're essentially asking for capabilities that are lesser than what we already had through the old Email Settings API.

**Is there any way we can just "swap" and downgrade scopes, or add the new scope without customer intervention?** Google have done similar things in the past with deprecated APIs.

EDIT: in case it matters, we're accessing the Gmail API using a service account so we can access the details of any user like we could with the Email Settings API.

(If the answer is "no", I'm hoping an official Google person will see this and take this idea away for consideration. Alternatively, allow us to *retrieve* signature settings with the "compose" scope since appending a signature to an email you're sending is a genuine use-case.)

Comment: Are you requesting for Google to change the scopes for you in their servers internally? Try checking the [Migration Guide from Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/migrate-from-email-settings#authorizing_requests) and update your app in the marketplace if possible.

Comment: Yes - I'm requesting that Google change the scopes internally, or provide some means where we can "trade in" our Email Settings API scope for a newer Gmail API scope relevant to email settings. I've seen the guide you mention, but it doesn't address this question. I'm assuming that changing the scopes within the Marketplace will immediately require end users to re-authorise our App because of the newly added scope, which is what I'm looking to avoid since we're not actually requesting any new capabilities; just the same capabilities via a different API.

Comment: @ChrisWood how did you end up addressing? Still no answer from Google.

Comment: @MeLight nobody ever responded, either here or via other routes, sadly. We ended up having to start a new project in the developer console and then do a marketing campaign to get users to switch to the new one. Google have been no help at all, either with this or with the more recent changes around restricted scopes in Gmail.