# Downgrade gmail.modify scope to gmail.readonly without re-prompting user

Tags: oauth-2.0, gmail, gmail-api

Currently I have an application that requests `gmail.modify` Auth scope. Due to updates in the [Gmail scope compliance policy](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/elevating-user-trust-in-our-api-ecosystems) I would like to downgrade from the broader `gmail.modify` scope (which gives access to "All read/write operations except immediate, permanent deletion of threads and messages, bypassing Trash.") to the subset functionality granted by `gmail.readonly`. It appears [Gmail Auth scopes have a heirarchy](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes), where `gmail.modify` is a superset of `gmail.readonly`.

I would like to downgrade (or swap) currently authorized accounts from `gmail.modify` to `gmail.readonly` ***without having to re-prompt users with the Auth Consent***. Is this possible given `gmail.readonly` is narrower? Or will I have to ask all existing users to grant `gmail.readonly`?

I found a somewhat similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41703653/possible-to-swap-oauth2-gmail-api-scopes), but there is no answer or follow up on the outcome.

Comment: did you make any progress on this? I asked the similar question a while back, but now running into it again because I want to downgrade https://mail.google.com/ scope into two lower level (more restrictive) scopes.

Comment: PS - the only way we got around a big-bang change in that similar question was to create a whole new project in the Developer Console with the new permissions and contact every customer. It was horrid, but did at least avoid it suddenly changing and breaking for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

`gmail.readonly` is a restricted scope. You cannot be granted this privilge without consent from the user. This scope has read access to all resources and metadata.

Comment: It is actually a restricted scope [1], which is above sensitive in the hierarchy. `gmail.modify` is also a restricted scope however, and contains all read/write operations except deletion - so it can do anything `gmail.readonly` can.

[1] https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914#restricted-scopes

Comment: Maybe it was not entirely clear, but I already have consent from users to use `gmail.modify`. Since this is a broader scope than `gmail.readonly` I want to change all users who have consented `gmail.modify` to the narrower `gmail.readonly` without having to re-prompt them with the OAuth consent screen. Hopefully that clears up any confusion.

Comment: @marnett - Thank you. I meant restricted scope.

Comment: @marnett - I am not 100% sure, but I believe any change in scopes will require reauthorization. I have not tested your example in the real world.

Answer (score 0):

Your users should be able to continue using their existing tokens that contain the `gmail.modify` scope until their refresh tokens need to be renewed, at which point they would need to re-authorize anyway. Someone from Google support told me they don't plan on invalidating existing refresh tokens due to this new policy, and they will expire in the regular ways still. Just start authorizing new users with `gmail.readonly` and continue to use the existing tokens you have.